# Setting keyboard layout on Fedora 38/39

Tags: fedora, gnome, keyboard-layout

since Fedora 38 installation I have a problem with keyboard layout setting. Probably during the installation of F38 I've chosen en_US and cs_CZ locales and keyboard layouts. And now I cannot find where and how to change it. I've checked with [Fedora docs](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/fedora/latest/system-administrators-guide/basic-system-configuration/System_Locale_and_Keyboard_Configuration/), my setting is

```bash
$ localectl status
System Locale: LANG=en_US.utf8
    VC Keymap: us
   X11 Layout: us
```

In "Gnome Settings" > "Keyboard" I have only single layout "English (US)" but still when I change keyboard layout by pressing Alt+Shift the kbd layout is switched to Czech (qwertz). I want to get rid of this Czech (qwertz) layout and add Czech (qwerty) instead.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in Gnome Tweaks - I've turned on keyboard layout switching with Right-Shift + Right-Ctrl and that automatically added extra Czech kbd layout. It's pitty it's not possible to use only meta keys to switch layouts. (or is it?)
[image]